# Entidades aninhadas / lista aninhadas no Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Possuo duas tabelas Chapa e Candidato com a semelhante estrutura:

```
TABLE Chapa (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
TABLE Candidato (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    chapa_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

E as respectivas entidades:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @Entity */
class Chapa
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Uma Chapa possui Muitos Candidatos.
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Candidato", mappedBy="chapa")
     */
    private $candidatos;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->candidatos = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Candidato
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Muitos Candidaatos possuem Uma Chapa.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Chapa", inversedBy="candidatos")
     * @JoinColumn(name="chapa_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $chapa;
    // ...
}
```

Com o seguinte queryBuilder eu recebo o resultado:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ch')
           ->select('ch.numero, cds.nome' )
           ->leftJoin('ch.candidatos', 'cds')
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();

// Resultado
{
  "data": [
    {
      "numero": "Chapa 10",
      "nome": "Candidato 1"
    },
    {
      "numero": "Chapa 10",
      "nome": "Candidato 2"
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Como proceder para receber o seguinte resultado (aninhado)?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "numero": "Chapa 10",
      "candidatos": [
        {
          "nome": "Candidato 1"
        },
        {    
          "nome": "Candidato 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

Comment: O resultado que você está mostrando me parece ser gerado por outra camada em sua aplicação. Poderia nos mostrar o trecho de código que recebe o retorno do banco e processa para gerar este JSON?

Comment: Naturalmente não é o Doctrine que retorna o JSON. Existe uma classe HTTP ResponseBag que converte o retorno do Doctrine para JSON, mantendo a estrutura original retornada do banco.

Resolvi o problema retornado o resultado do Doctrine como array e iterando sobre o mesmo pra organizar da maneira esperada. Minha questão era se o Doctrine per se conseguiria já retornar nesse formato, com base no relacionamento atual das duas entidades.

Comment: SIm, o Doctrine consegue retornar no formato correto que você está esperando, por isso questionei como está construido a camada que transforma em JSON.